# How can i get the encoded file data using FIlepond encode plugin

Tags: reactjs, filepond

I am trying to get the encoded base64 data and pass it along with other form fields

```
registerPlugin(FilePondPluginFileEncode);

<FilePond
  ref={ref => (this.pond = ref)}
  onaddfile={this.handleFileUploader}
  onremovefile={this.handleRemoveFile}
  name="passport"
  acceptedFileTypes={mimeTypes}
  allowFileEncode={true}
/>
```

Comment: Why not pass the file object if I may ask?

Comment: please can you show me an example

Comment: You can append file objects or blobs to FormData and then POST the form data https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#Example